# Sum of a geometric sequence where index doesn't start from $~1~$

Tags: sequences-and-series, systems-of-equations, geometric-series

Assume $~n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq3}~$
$$\underbrace{\color{red}{
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=n+1}^{+\infty}(0.6)\cdot(0.4)^{x-1}=(0.4)^n
\end{align}
}
}_{\text{I want to derive RHS from LHS}}
$$

I know the following formula which could be applied to derive the red eqn.

$$S_n = {a\left(1-r^n\right)\over(1-r)}$$

$S_n~$represents the sum of a geometric sequence where $~a~$ stands for an initial term and $~r~$ takes a common ratio, and $~n\in\mathbb{N}~$ holds.

The problem is that, the index which is on the shoulder of $~(0.4)~$ doesn't start with $~1~$ and my brain has stopped thinking.

Can anyone give me some hint(s)?

BTW, I've written this post from my smartphone so my reply may be late since it is hard to write MathJax codes using the phone so far.

**ADD**

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{x=n+1}^{+\infty}(0.6)\cdot(0.4)^{x-1}\\&=
\end{align}$$

Comment: It may help to write out the first few terms of your series.

Comment: I will do it  :D

Comment: The $a$ in the formula refers to the first term of the geometric series. It doesn't specify an index! In this case, $a$ is the result of plugging in the first index $x = n + 1$ into the formula $(0.4)(0.6)^{x - 1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula for the sum of a (convergent) infinite geometric series is
$$\frac{\text{FirstTerm}}{1-\text{CommonRatio}}$$
where FirstTerm is the first term of the series and CommonRatio is the ratio of each term (except the first) to the one before. The series is convergent if the absolute value of CommonRatio is less than one. In your example, $\text{FirstTerm}=(0.6)\cdot(0.4)^n$ and $\text{CommonRatio}=0.4$.

The formula for the sum of a finite geometric series with $\text{CommonRatio}\neq1$ is
$$\frac{\text{FirstTerm}-\text{FirstMissingTerm}}{1-\text{CommonRatio}}$$
where FirstMissingTerm is the term that would come next if the series were to be continued.

Answer (score 3):

You have
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=n+1}^{\infty} (0.6) (0.4)^{x-1} 
&= 0.6 \left((0.4)^n + (0.4)^{n+1} + \cdots{} \right) \\
&= 0.6 \, (0.4)^n \left( 1 + 0.4 + (0.4)^2 + \cdots{} \right) \\
&= 0.6 \, (0.4)^n \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} (0.4)^x \\
&= 0.6 \, (0.4)^n \frac{1}{1-0.4} \\
&= (0.4)^n.
\end{align}

Comment: thanks Sammy...

Comment: Using the `align` environment allows you to make the $=$ signs line up vertically without having to hard-code a bunch of horizontal spaces. Click `Edit` to see the changes and/or have a look at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more $\LaTeX$/MathJax hints.